# Forcing postback on selection of a radio button

Tags: html

I know this is simple as cake but I've been using ASP.NET controls for way too long.  I assume you have to do this via javascript with a regular XHTML input tag?

Comment: Do you want to submit the form to the current page, or redirect to a URL after you select the input?

Comment: to a url... I need to do some server-side calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect to a URL after selecting a radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" onclick="window.location.href='/my/desired/url.aspx';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call a javascript method that sets window.location

```
function redirect() {
  window.location = 'http://whatever...'
}
```